# Como puedo redondear a 6 decimales un input que ya tiene valores (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ```
> { "data": "ProductoCantidad"
> ```

```
                , render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<input type="number" id="txtCantidad" style="font-size: 12px;" class=" form-control full-width text-lg-center" value="' + data + '" >';
                }
            },
```

> Como puedo hacer para que los valores  que son los de la imagen, al momento de yo poder cambiarlos automaticamente me los coloque en 6 decimales.
> `

Comment: Que te los *coloque en 6 decimales*? es decir, que aparezca el punto decimal y seis ceros a la derecha? Puedes dar un ejemplo?

Comment: tal vez algo de esto te pueda servir: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#permitir_valores_decimales

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.